# C# RavenDB delete

Tags: ravendb

I have the following object:
WordOccurrence, which has two attributes:
- string word.
- int occurrences.
I would like to do the following, without getting an exeception (-:
WordOccurrence w1 = new WordOccurrence() {Word ="Hey", Occurrence = 1};
WordOccurrence w2 = new WordOccurrence() {Word ="Hey", Occurrence = 1};

now I would like to store the first one , w1, but with w2 to delete him.

session.store(w1);
session.delete(w2); -> gets exeception...

is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

Please try formatting the code in your question, and rephrasing what you are trying to do. It isn't clear if you're expecting that saving `w2` should refer to the same object as `w1`, but they aren't - even if the ID is the same that isn't how Raven will handle the delete. You need to either delete the object you just stored *immediately after you call SaveChanges* (which I don't understand why you would want to do), or in the more likely scenario `Load` it at some point later on and then call `Delete`:

```
var w1Id = string.empty;
using(session)
{
  var w1 = new WordOccurrence { Word="Hey", Occurrence=1};
  session.store(w1);
  session.SaveChanges();
  w1Id = w1.Id; 
  //if you aren't declaring the Id property for some reason...
  w1Id = session.Advanced.GetDocumentId(w1);
}

//somewhere else in the code
using(session)
{
  var w1 = session.Load<WordOccurrence>(w1Id);
  session.Delete(w1);
  session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Bottom line is that you can't delete something you just told the session to `Store`, before you even called `SaveChanges`. If you're trying to undo a `Store` operation, perhaps because the user hit an undo button, just don't call `SaveChanges` (if it's the only operation in the session), or use `Session.Advanced.Evict(w1)` to evit that object from the session.

If you are expecting the Word property to be the Id of the document you can make that happen by [customizing the DocumentStore conventions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/Ly10rvbVrcM)